# The semiperimeter of a right-angled triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $\triangle ABC$ is a right-angled triangle ($\measuredangle C=90^\circ$) and $CD\perp AB,D\in AB$. If $p_{\triangle ACD}=p_2$ and $p_{\triangle BCD}=p_1$ are the semiperimeters of $\triangle ACD$ and $\triangle BCD$, find the semiperimeter $p$ of triangle $\triangle ABC$.

[image]

We have $\triangle ACD\sim\triangle CBD\sim\triangle ABC$. In the authors' solution they have concluded from the similarity of the three triangles: $$\dfrac{p_1}{AC}=\dfrac{p_2}{BC}=\dfrac{p}{AB}=k\Rightarrow p_1=kAC,p_2=kBC,p=kAB$$ I really don't see how we can get that ratio from it.

Then they wrote $(kAB)^2=(kAC)^2+(kBC)^2\Rightarrow p^2=p_1^2+p_2^2$.

For the first equality, we can look at it as if we have multiplied $AB^2=AC^2+BC^2$ by $k^2$ to get $$(kAB)^2=(kAC)^2+(kBC)^2,$$ right? That's the reason it holds.

Comment: We do not need that $k$ explicitly, we need only a relation between $p;p_1,p_2$, and since these numbers are proportional to the sides, and we know a (homogeneous)  relation for the sides... Which is explicitly the question? [How to get $k$?] or [Why did the(ir) proof work?] ?

Answer (score 1):

By similarity of $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta ACD$, we have
$$
\frac{CD}{AC} = \frac{BC}{AB}, \qquad \frac{AD}{AC} = \frac{AC}{AB}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{p_1}{AC} = \frac{AD+CD+AC}{2AC} = \frac{AC+BC+AB}{2AB} = \frac{p}{AB}.
$$
You can make the same calculation for $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta BCD$ to get
$$
\frac{p_2}{BC} = \frac{p}{AB}.
$$
If we name this ratio $k$, then we can multiply the Pythagorean relationship of the side lengths of the right triangle $\Delta ABC$ by $k^2$ like you said and obtain
$$
p = \sqrt{p_1^2 + p_2^2}.
$$